# How to calculate a running total that is a distinct sum of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider this dataset:

```
id       site_id type_id value   date
-------  ------- ------- ------- -------------------
1        1       1       50      2017-08-09 06:49:47
2        1       2       48      2017-08-10 08:19:49
3        1       1       52      2017-08-11 06:15:00
4        1       1       45      2017-08-12 10:39:47
5        1       2       40      2017-08-14 10:33:00
6        2       1       30      2017-08-09 07:25:32
7        2       2       32      2017-08-12 04:11:05
8        3       1       80      2017-08-09 19:55:12
9        3       2       75      2017-08-13 02:54:47
10       2       1       25      2017-08-15 10:00:05
```

I would like to construct a query that returns a running total for each date by type. I can get close with a window function, but I only want the latest value for each site to be summed for the running total (a simple window function will not work because it sums **all** values up to a date--not just the last values for each site). So I guess it could be better described as a running distinct total?

The result I'm looking for would be like this:

```
type_id date                sum
------- ------------------- -------
1       2017-08-09 06:49:47 50
1       2017-08-09 07:25:32 80
1       2017-08-09 19:55:12 160
1       2017-08-11 06:15:00 162
1       2017-08-12 10:39:47 155
1       2017-08-15 10:00:05 150
2       2017-08-10 08:19:49 48
2       2017-08-12 04:11:05 80
2       2017-08-13 02:54:47 155
2       2017-08-14 10:33:00 147
```

The key here is that the sum is not a running sum. It should only be the sum of the most recent values for each site, *by type*, at each date. I think I can help explain it by walking through the result set I've provided above. For my explanation, I'll walk through the original data chronologically and try to explain the expected result.

The first row of the result starts us off, at 2017-08-09 06:49:47, where chronologically, there is only one record of type 1 and it is 50, so that is our sum for 2017-08-09 06:49:47.

The second row of the result is at 2017-08-09 07:25:32, at this point in time we have 2 unique sites with values for type_id = 1. They have values of 50 and 30, so the sum is 80.

The third row of the result occurs at 2017-08-09 19:55:12, where now we have 3 sites with values for type_id = 1. 50 + 30 + 80 = 160.

The fourth row is where it gets interesting. At 2017-08-11 06:15:00 there are 4 records with a type_id = 1, but 2 of them are for the same site. I'm only interested in the most recent value for each site so the values I'd like to sum are: 30 + 80 + *52* resulting in **162**.

The 5th row is similar to the 4th since the value for site_id:1, type_id:1 has changed again and is now 45. This results in the latest values for type_id:1 at 2017-08-12 10:39:47 are now: 30 + 80 + 45 = 155.

Reviewing the 6th row is also interesting when we consider that at 2017-08-15 10:00:05, site 2 has a new value for type_id 1, which gives us: 80 + 45 + **25** = **150** for 2017-08-15 10:00:05.

Comment: you need to partition by type_id I believe

Comment: something like this : select type_id
        , date
        , sum(value) over (partition by type_id order by date)
from table
order by type_id, date

Comment: I can understand where the values for your first three sum values (50,80,160) come from but not sure why / how the fourth row is 162?

Comment: type_id 1 only has 3 unique site_id's. Why does your expected outcome then have 5 rows for type_id 1 when you only want to sum the latest value for each site_id per type?

Comment: @stevee1986, the 162 in the forth row is because I only want the most recent value for each site, by type. So, the 50 from site 1 is now replaced by a 52, making the sum of 30 + 80 + 52 = 162.

Comment: @FuzzyTree, I would like the sum at each change in time so I can chart this historically.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a cumulative total (running total) by including an `ORDER BY` clause in your window frame.

```
select
  type_id,
  date,
  sum(value) over (partition by type_id order by date) as sum
from your_table;
```

The `ORDER BY` works because

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is the same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

Comment: Thanks @Andy-Carlson, but a running sum is not what I'm after. I only want the sum of the most recent values for each site, grouped by type_id. I'll try and make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      type_id,
            date,
            SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY type_id ORDER BY type_id, date) - (SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY type_id, site_id ORDER BY type_id, date) - value) AS sum
FROM        your_table
ORDER BY    type_id,
            date
```

Comment: This is really clever! It works well if we only have one site that has multiple numbers for a type. I've added another row to my dataset (2017-08-15 10:00:05) which causes a change in the type 1 value for site 2. This causes your suggestion a little trouble since its only dealing with the current site on a row by row basis. Do you have any ideas on solving that?